# Maven doesn't include JAR to the classpath

Tags: eclipse, maven, maven-3

I am working with Maven3 to build a REST API with Jersey. Maven comes to download all JARs (from my enterprise repository) and puts them in `/home/xxx/.m2/repository` but it doesn't include them at the classpath of my project in Eclipse.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you using an Eclipse Maven plugin? There's no reason Maven would magically know you're doing anything with Eclipse unless (a) you're using one of the eclipse tasks, or (b) using a Maven plugin.

Comment: yes i am working with an Eclipse Maven Plugin @DaveNewton

Comment: When you right-click on the project in Eclipse, can you select **Maven** > **Update project...**?

Comment: @E-Riz, yes , i did it by it is not working , there is no JARs in the classpath !

Comment: Show what the **Java Build Path** > **Libraries** tab looks like. There should be a *Maven Dependencies* section.

Comment: Try switching in another workspace and import the maven project again. Eclipse someties gets corrupted. Or download Eclipse again.